# Why doesn't set -e cause a failure with `false || false && true`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can't figure out a fitting title, I don't understand the behavior in dash/bash. Namely I am using set -e to bail out if a command fails, and command groups to handle the positive result.

ie. the general scheme is:

```
[ ! wantcommand ] || command
```

Than means the command only gets executed if needed, and a failure will automatically kill the script.

There might be some postprocessing necessary, in that case I use this:

```
[ ! wantcommand ] || { command && postprocess; }
```

This has led to some curious bughunting, as this **wont kill the shell** and I cant get behind the reason. I have to go through some chunks of shell code now, but would like to understand the reason.

for testing:

```
bash -c 'set -e; { false || false && echo "post" ; }; echo "ec $?"'
```

or:

```
bash -c 'set -e; { set -e; false || false && echo "post" ; }; echo "ec $?"'
```

Note: I am not asking for a fix, but primary **why the returncode is 1, but the shell wont quit**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`set -e` only bails on **unchecked** failures.

When you branch on a failure (using `if`, `until`, `while`, `&&` or `||`), that failure is checked.

If the specification were not written in this manner, short-circuiting boolean operations could not effectively be used for flow control because the false branches would always cause an exit.

---

To quote from [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set), with emphasis added:

> When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons listed in [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) or by returning an exit status greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit, as if by executing the exit special built-in utility with no arguments, with the following exceptions:
>
> 1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline itself shall be considered.
> 2. The -e setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, or `elif` reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word, or **any command of an AND-OR list other than the last**.
> 3. If the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell command was the result of a failure while `-e` was being ignored, then `-e` shall not apply to this command.
>
> This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately. For example, in:
>
> ```
> set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two
> ```
>
> the `false` command causes the subshell to exit without executing `echo one`; however, `echo two` is executed because the exit status of the pipeline `(false; echo one) | cat` is zero.

Note that this specification has changed over time; shells implementing a prior revision of the POSIX specification may not precisely comply with the version quoted here.

---

To inject some opinion here -- I'd strongly suggest reading [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and ensuring that you fully understand all behaviors described therein before making the decision to use `set -e` rather than implementing explicit error-handling by hand. The [FVUE wiki](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling) further describes the distinctions in behavior between `set -e` in bash-native mode and POSIX mode, which should likewise be understood.

Comment: Yeah, explicit error handling just got way less messy in my opinion, ugly to look at but at least easy to grasp. Can`t say I fully understood the behavior, it seems quite counter-intuitive to me. Will read through the links later, thanks
Part of my misunderstanding seems to come from using scripts in make, which will always fail if ec != 0, no matter what